# Plugins compile order in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to create an SBT plugin that provides common plugins and settings for my organization's projects (something like a Maven parent POM).
Since most of these settings should also be present in the commons project itself, I'm adding the sources as unmanagedSourceDirectories in plugins.sbt so the autoplugins I define for the proper project are also present on the meta-project (a neat trick I took from sbt-release plugin).

Things work just fine, except I still need to duplicate the addSbtPlugin entries when I want a plugin for booth my proper project and meta-project. If I don't do this, my proper-project won't compile since the plugins' classes are not loaded.

I tried moving all the shared plugin dependencies to a separate autoplugin assuming SBT would compile it and add the library dependencies to the meta-project so they would be there when my common plugin is compiled, but it doesn't work.

I would like to understand why this fails and if there is some way to thinker with the compilation order to somehow make it work. If not, I would gladly hear any alternatives you guys know to avoid having to maintain duplicate versions of all my shared plugins.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

**project structure**

```
/common
 |-build.sbt
 |-/project
 |  |-plugins.sbt
 |-/src/main/scala/package
    |-Dependencies.scala
    |-MyCommonPlugin.scala
```

**build.sbt**

```
sbtPlugin := true
name := "common"
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value.getParentFile / "src" / "main" / "scala"
```

**Dependencies.scala**

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

//Plugins I intend to share between build.sbt and plugins.sbt
object Dependencies extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = allRequirements
  override lazy val projectSettings = super.projectSettings ++ Seq(
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.8.5")
  )
}
```

**MyCommonPlugin.scala**

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

//this import fails! object sbt is not a member of package com.typesafe
import com.typesafe.sbt.GitBranchPrompt.{ projectSettings => gitBranchPromptSettings }

object MyCommonPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = allRequirements
  override lazy val projectSettings =
    super.projectSettings ++
    gitBranchPromptSettings ++
    Seq(
      // My common settings
    )
}
```

To make this code work I would need to repeat the `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.8.5")` on plugins.sbt.